# Aliasing table when making relation

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

I have a table TableWithLongerName which has connection foreign key to TableWithLongName. With Go-Pg I want to retrieve data of TableWithLongerName with data from TableWithLongName embedded to it. But unfortunately TableWithLongName has column VeryLongColumnName.

When I run `query.Relation("TableWithLongName")` it returns error

```
can't find column table_with_long_name__very_long_c in Model TableWithLongerName
```

I have create alias for domain in TableWithLongName but it gets overwritten.

Comment: Don't use mixed case identifiers, or you are doomed to quoting them for the rest of your life.

Comment: Can you post a small script witch can show what are you exactly trying